# Different mouseover and mouseout images within Input tags

Tags: button, hover, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have a custom (IE I found it on the internet) PayPal donate button. I want it to have 2 different images - the mouseout image, and the mouseover image. I changed

```
<input type="image" src='/images/icons/donate.png' border="0" name="submit" alt="">
```

to

```
<input type="image" onmouseout="this.src='/images/icons/donate.png'" onmouseover="this.src='/images/icons/hover_donate.png'" border="0" name="submit" alt="">
```

The two different images work properly, however, when the page loads initially, neither image appears until I mouseover at least once. After that, they're find, it works how it should. I was wondering if there was a way to fix this, preferably with CSS. Here's the complete section of code I'm talking about (minus identifying information), and an image (or link, rather, since I don't have the rep to post images) of what I'm talking about.

```
            <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="valueHere">
            <input type="image" onmouseover="this.src='/images/icons/hover_donate.png'" onmouseout="this.src='/images/icons/donate.png'" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPa$
            <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
            </form>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmmCm.png)

The top one is what I see on a fresh page (with ctrl+f5, to ensure it's pulling it from the server and not my cache), and the bottom ones are the button and the hover button, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Give id on input field and give that a background-image (the image that you want to appear on default without hovering)

```
<style type="text/css">
   #donation{background-image:url(images/icons/donate.png);}
</style>

<input type="image" id="donation" onmouseout="this.src='/images/icons/donate.png'" onmouseover="this.src='/images/icons/hover_donate.png'" border="0" name="submit" alt=""> And
```